# MVC Ajax won't pass data into the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

heres my code. So basically the code below suppose to send the classId into the Test(int classId), however, when I tried to click the button, it just didnt go into the server, seems the POST is not working. Anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(int classid)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<body>


    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
     {
         var buttonid = "btnSubmit" + i;

         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Name)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].ClassName)
         <input name="submit" id="@buttonid" type="button" data-classid="@Model[i].ClassID" value="Go to class Form" class="btn btn-default MyButtonClass" style="font-size: 14px"/>

     }

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("click",
            ".MyButtonClass",
            function() {

                var id = $(this).data("classid");
                alert(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/StudentController/Test",
                    data: { classid: id }
                });

            });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: So what is happening with your current code? Is the ajax call being made ? Check your browser dev tools (console tab and network tab) and see whether the call is made and if yes, what response it is getting back

Comment: Your url appears to be wrong.  instead of StudentController, just use Student: "/Student/Test".

Answer (score 0):

Your url appears to be wrong. instead of StudentController, just use Student: "/Student/Test".